# Remove Node from Binary Tree - Return Set of Trees Back

Tags: scala

I was kinda just pegging away at this problem for fun and kinda hit a road block with it and couldn't find much information on it online.  I want to create an algorithm in Scala where when you remove a node of some value from a tree, it will return the set of trees it creates.  For example the Tree

```
   1
  / \
 3   4
 /\  /\
4  5 6 2
```

If we remove 4 then it would return trees as follows:

```
 [   1     , 6 , 2 ] 
 [  /              ]
 [ 3               ]
 [ \               ]
 [  5              ]
```

What I have so far is as follows:

```
object TreeStructure {

  trait Tree {
    def isEmpty(): Boolean

    def equals(other: Tree): Boolean

    def diff(other: Tree): Tree

    def remove(value: Int): List[Tree]

    def removeNode(value: Int): Tree
  }

  case class Node(var left: Tree, var right: Tree, value: Int) extends Tree {
    override def isEmpty = false;

    override def equals(other: Tree): Boolean = other match {
      case x: Node => this.value == x.value && this.left.equals(x.left) && this.right.equals(x.right)
      case _ => false
    }

    override def diff(other: Tree): Tree = {
      if (this.equals(other)) new EmptyNode()
      else new Node(this.left.diff(other), this.right.diff(other), this.value)
    }

    override def removeNode(value: Int): Tree = {
      if (this.value == value) {
        EmptyNode()
      } else {
        new Node(this.left.removeNode(value),this.right.removeNode(value), this.value)
      }
    }

    override def remove(value: Int): List[Tree] = {
      (List(this.removeNode(value)) ++ left.remove(value) ++ right.remove(value))
    }
  }

  case class Leaf(var value: Int) extends Tree {
    override def isEmpty(): Boolean = false

    override def equals(other: Tree): Boolean = other match {
      case y: Leaf => this.value == y.value
      case _ => false
    }

    override def diff(other: Tree): Tree = {
      if (this.equals(other)) EmptyNode();
      else this
    }

    override def remove(value: Int): List[Tree] = {
      if(this.value == value) Nil
      else List(this)
    }

    override def removeNode(value:Int): Tree = {
      if(this.value == value) EmptyNode()
      else this
    }
  }

  case class EmptyNode() extends Tree {
    override def isEmpty(): Boolean = true

    override def equals(other: Tree): Boolean = other match {
      case x: EmptyNode => true
      case _ => false
    }

    override def diff(other: Tree): Tree = new EmptyNode()

    override def remove(value: Int): List[Tree] = Nil

    override def removeNode(value:Int): Tree = new EmptyNode()
  }


  val t1 = new Node(new Leaf(15), new Leaf(13), 0)
  val t2 = new Node(new Leaf(15), new Leaf(13), 0)
  val t3 = new Node(new Node(new Leaf(3), new Leaf(13), 0), new Leaf(25), 30)

  val t4 = new Leaf(13)
  val boo = t1.equals(t2)
  t3.diff(t1)
  t3.remove(30)
}
```

I'm relatively newer to Scala, any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer which could probably be written more succinctly, but I hope it somewhat clearly expresses the algorithm:

```
case class N[T](value: T, children: List[N[T]] = Nil) {
  def remove(t: T) = {
    val r = _remove(t)
    r._1.toList ++ r._2
  }

  def _remove(t: T): (Option[N[T]], List[N[T]]) =
    if(value == t) (None, children.map(_._remove(t)).flatMap{ case (c, o) => c.toList ++ o})
    else {
      val results = children.map(_._remove(t))
      val me = this.copy(children = results.flatMap(_._1))
      val others = results.flatMap(_._2)
      (Some(me), others)
    }
}
```